# What does the parameter AExecDirect in ExecSQL do?

Tags: delphi, firedac

I was reading the documentation of the class `TFDCustomQuery` and I'm curious about the meaning of the parameter `AExecDirect` in `function ExecSQL(AExecDirect: Boolean): LongInt; overload;`.

The documentation (http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomQuery.ExecSQL) does not explains what this parameter does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass **True** to the **AExecDirect** parameter, FireDAC will omit command preparation before its execution (and a few things related to the used DBMS). Its purpose therefore is just for commands executed only once without explicit command preparation.

There's an important thing to note about this [**ExecSQL**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomQuery.ExecSQL) method overload. Calling this one modifies the [**DirectExecute**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDResourceOptions.DirectExecute) option (by the **AExecDirect** parameter value) of the object, which might not be expected.

A problem can arise in situations, when one calls this method overload with the **True** value passed to the **AExecDirect** parameter, expecting that later calls of the other [**ExecSQL**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomQuery.ExecSQL) overloads calls will implicitly prepare the command. They won't, as the [**DirectExecute**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDResourceOptions.DirectExecute) option will be enabled.

So, the [**DirectExecute**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Option.TFDResourceOptions.DirectExecute) option reference actually describes this parameter (so as this parameter of this method overload sets this option):

> Controls the preparation of SQL statements.
>
> Use the DirectExecute property to specify whether FireDAC should
>   prepare an SQL statement before its execution (False) or execute it
>   directly (True). The default value is False.
>
> This property was introduced at first for MS SQL Server support. The
>   prepared and the direct execution may have different effects, and even
>   the prepared execution may fail. If you will get peculiar errors, then
>   try to set DirectExecute to True.